# MySQL query to determine if certain product return is already served

Tags: mysql

I have a little problem with regards to my SQL query. I have a transactions table where all product purchases, orders, and returns are saved. When a user enters a purchase, I save an entry into that table with a positive quantity. When a user enters an order, I save an entry to that table with a negative quantity. When a user enters a product return, I also save a positive quantity in it. When I need to know the current inventory I just sum up all the entries of the product.

What I need to know is if a returned product still in the inventory or not. I need to know this so that I can inform the user that there is a returned good stock.

Here is the structure of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_history` (
  `lineno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `profileno` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `detailno` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `profiledate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `productid` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unitid` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lotnumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `free` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiry` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transactiontype` enum('O','P','PC','RT') DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lineno`),
  KEY `update_index` (`profileno`,`profiledate`,`transactiontype`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5497 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query